# Show page by variable ?page= and some help needed?

Tags: php

Hi m i want to display some page via the variable ?page= its giving error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\AppServ\www\index.php on line 11

```
<?php
include 'assets/config.php';
$page = $_GET["page"];
if ($page == "script") {
include("/pages/script.php");
}
if ($page == "how") {
include(/pages/"how.php");
?>
```

Please i need help  on that and also

i want to redirect urls via a new variable ?go= page on my website my code Please customize it ....

```
*<?php
include '/assets/config.php';
$goto = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$RedirectTo = "$goto";
header("Location: $RedirectTo");
exit;
?>*
```

Thanks

Comment: Read the line `include(/pages/"how.php");` closely.

Answer (score 1):

Change this as well

```
$RedirectTo = "$goto";
```

To:

```
$RedirectTo = $goto;
```

Comment: its not thats error but i want to make a url redirect script bu urls

Comment: like site.com/?go=http://google.com

Comment: `header('Location: http://example.com/?go=google.com');`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
include("/pages/script.php");
include(/pages/"how.php");
```

to

```
include("pages/script.php");
include("pages/how.php");
```

Comment: thanks and for my pther script ? to redirect urls please need help

Comment: See @Professor Zooms answer :)